# EF Core FromSqlRaw - The call is ambigous between the following methods

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have been using EF 7 Core for SQL Server and recently added EF 7 Core for Cosmos DB.

However, after installing the EF Core Cosmos provider, I'm getting this error.

> Error CS0121  The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet, string, params object[])'
> and 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.CosmosQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet, string, params object[])'

Both extension methods use the same namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, so, I cannot resolve this by specifying the namespace.

Is there a way to choose which extension method to use other than  using namespace?

Comment: instead of `a.MyConflictingExtensionMethod(foo => foo.Bar());`, you can use `MyNamespace.MyConflictingExtensionMethod(a, foo => foo.Bar());`

Comment: @Cid both extension methods have the same namespace. So, I cannot use the namespace to choose.

Comment: They don't : `RelationalQueryableExtensions` vs `CosmosQueryableExtensions`

Comment: They do. RelationalQueryableExtensions and CosmosQueryableExtensions are classes, not the namespace. But...I think I know what you are saying. So, you are saying to call those like methods, not like extension methods? I think that would work.

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, I'm adding Cosmos EF provider to use Cosmos DB. And I'm using one namespace, not two. Both SQL Server and Cosmos DB EF provider extension methods have the same namespace.

Comment: You can also use [Aliases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#using-alias) to differentiate these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a workaround. Previously, I used them as an extension method like this.

```
context.Set<ABC>().FromSqlRaw("select a from b");
```

But I realized that I could use the extension methods just like the regular static methods.

```
RelationalQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw(context.Set<ABC>(), "select a from b")

CosmosQueryableExtensions.FromSqlRaw(context.Set<ABC>(), "select a from b")
```

This way, I can choose which extension method to use, even if they have the same namespace.

Thank you for the comment Cid.